# partiQL statement(where pk in [pk1, pk2]) into DynamoDBQueryExpression

Tags: indexeddb

I've been searching ways to query multiple related items based on GSI. Unfortunately batchLoad doesn't work with GSI that I'm looking to use DynamoDBQueryExpression for specific query type.

According to this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html

If we do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM "Orders"
WHERE PK IN [PK1, PK2, PK3]
```

it would be still considered as query not scan.

Thus, based on research, I should be using "filterExpression" in order to use the "IN" clause as key-condition doesn't support "IN". However the problem I'm facing is that DynamoDBQueryExpression would require key-condition.

**Question: ** Is it not possible to achieve query above with DynamoDBQueryExpression?

Code I tried is

```
        final Map<String, AttributeValue> pksCondition = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue> () {
            {
                put(":pkList", new AttributeValue(pkList));
            }
        };

        final String filterPk = "UniqueId IN (:pkList);

        final DynamoDBQueryExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression()
                .withIndexName(DynamoDBConstants.GSI_TABLE)
                .withFilterExpression(filterPk)
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(pksCondition)
                .withConsistentRead(false);

        final List<resultRecord> resultRecords = dynamoDBMapper.query(Result.class, queryExpression);
```